# Is there an alternative to Django crispy form for rendering Django form?

Tags: django, forms

Since I started to develop Django apps one year ago, I've use Django crispy form for rendering my forms.

For my new project, I want to change form rendering to look more like a 'desktop application'. This project will be a electronic data capture tool, with many forms with lots of fields.

I have found this design on Codepen by Rijdzuan Sampoerna I found very elegant and professionnal. It similar to Gitlab interfaces, I think.
So I would like a form rendering closed to this design.

I want to be able to have multiple fields in a same line (not only one column), with fields smaller,...

Before defining all css by myself, I wonder if there is a django form rendering I could use as crispy?

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42492379/12467282)? It still uses Django crispy forms, but it details how to apply your custom css. As far as Django forms are concerned, I will still prefer to use Django crispy forms as it's pretty convenient

Comment: No, but that what I was about to do if there is no other way. Thanks for references.